# Is there a unique solution?

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, differential-equations, curves-and-surfaces

Let $\mathbf{v}:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^2$ be a given continuous function and $t_0\in (a,b)$ a fixed point. Is it true that the following problem has a unique continuous solution $\mathbf{r}:(a,b)\to\mathbb{R}^2$:

$\left\{\begin{array}{ll}\mathbf{v}(t)=\mathbf{r}(t)+\displaystyle\lim_{s\searrow t} \frac{\mathbf{r}(s)-\mathbf{r}(t)}{||\mathbf{r}(s)-\mathbf{r}(t)||}\\ \mathbf{r}(t_0)=\mathbf{v}(t_0)+(\cos\theta_0,\sin\theta_0)\end{array}\right.$ ?

Comment: Did you ask an (almost) identical question here recently, or does my memory fail me?

Comment: It's far from that one. Anyway, that question has not a complete answer...

Comment: To make sense of the equation classically, $r$ has to be pointwise differentiable and by the continuity assumptions $C^1$. Your equation is a linear ODE, which can be solved explicitly (componentwise if you wish) and uniqueness is guaranteed by standard theory.

Comment: To justify Joonas' statement that $\mathbf{r}$ is $C^1$: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-differentiability#Application

Comment: Why do you need $||$ in the denominator if $s>t$? If written in ordinary notation what you are asking is to solve the differential equation $r'+r=v$ with an initial condition. As the equation is linear, a unique solution always exists.

Comment: @Bogdan: the denominator $\|\mathbf{s}-\mathbf{t}\|$ in your equation seems to refer to a vector quantity (norm and boldface); however **s** and **t** are real variables. Isn't that it was a typo for $\|\mathbf{r}(s)-\mathbf{r}(t)\|$?

Comment: I am really sorry for the typo. I have edited my post.

Comment: This is my research trying to extend the definition of regular curves, by introducing a new type of derivative. Having this I can study all curves that admit tangents at any point. For example $\mathbf{r}(t)=(\sqrt[3]{t^2}, t\cdot\sin\frac{1}{t})$ admits tangent at $t=0$ even though the lateral derivatives are inexistent. The question I have posed would be a linear differential equation for this type of derivative. I have tryed math.stackexchange, but I have not received any valuable answer. Thanks for understanding!

Comment: I think your differential equation has local existence with some additional assumptions, e.g $v\in C^1$ and $ v'(t_0)\cdot(v(t_0)-r(t_0))\neq0$. Maybe uniqueness.

Comment: However, this notion of derivative is  not easy to work with, mainly because it is not linear. We may say something on it mainly when $r$ is derivable with non vanishing derivative at $t_0$, so that it reduces to $r'(t_0)/\|r'(t_0)\|$.

Comment: I beleive in the uniqueness of the solution (with conditions from the statement) because this is the model of the bycicle, where $\mathbf{v}$ is the trace of the front wheel and $\mathbf{r}$ is the trace of the rear one. These type of curves (that admit that kind of derivatives) represents the best way to model the bycicle tracks. From intuition the way in which the front wheel moves uniquelly determines the way in which the rear wheel is moving. I hardly tried to find counterexamples, but I failed...